# BIRT 4.5 - Disable saving connectstring inside report.rptdesign, PHP to assign connectstring

Tags: php, mysql, tomcat, birt

I am using Birt 4.5 and PHP/MYSQL.
I am able to run birt reports with php. I have enabled tomcat and copied 'birt-runtime-4_5_0/WebViewerExample' to tomcat/webapps and renamed it to birt.

So I can run birt viewer with php;

```
<?php   
$fname = "report/test.rptdesign&__showtitle=false";
$dest = "http://localhost:8081/birt/frameset?__report=";
$dest .= $fname;
header("Location: $dest" );
?>
```

Above code is working fine. But report connectstring already saved in test.rptdesign file.
I want to remove DB login credentials from test.rptdesign file and assign it while report open with PHP.

I have tried with report parameters. But all the parameters will display on browser address-bar.

Is there any secure way to do this? This is very important when we need to change the database location. It is very hard to change the data source of each and every .rptdesign file.

Thank You,
Supun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe using report parameters to handle a database connection is the right way. In addition to the address-bar problem you mentionned, it will cause unexpected issues: for example you won't be able to use this database to feed the dataset of another report parameter.
With Tomcat the best approach is to externalize the database connection in a [connection pool](http://www.visioneo.org/knowledge-base/-/knowledge_base/article/122720): easy, robust, and reports might run significantly faster.

Alternatively the datasource can be externalized in a BIRT library (.rptlibrary) and shared across all report-designs: thus only the library needs to be updated when the database location is changing.

Comment: Hope this is the only way as I searched over the internet. Many thanks to your answer. Just wait for [symcbean](http://stackoverflow.com/users/223992/symcbean) to respond on below comment.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dominique that sending the database parameters via the query is most likely an inappropriate solution - and you've not given any explanation of whether this is a requirement of the system.

But it is quite trivial to proxy the request via PHP and decorate the URL with the required parameters, something like...

```
<?php

$_GET['__showtitle']=$_GET['__showtitle'] ? $_GET['__showtitle'] : 'false';
$_GET['__report']=$fname;  // NB this should be NULL in your code!
$_GET['dbuser']='a_db_user';
$_GET['passwd']='s3cr3t';

$qry=http_build_query($_GET);
$url="http://localhost:8081/birt/frameset?" . $qry;

// if its simply returning HTML, then just....
$fin=fopen($url, 'r');
while ($l=fgets($fin)) {
   print $l;
}
exit;
```

If the returned content contains relative links the you'll need to rewrite the output stream. If the content type is unusual or you want to project other headers (e.g. for caching) to the browser, then you'll need to use Curl, capture the headers and relay them.

Comment: fopen says `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`. Anyway I just want to know is there anyway to send connetion string credentials to tomcat->birt report via PHP (may using curl). It shoud be secure as well. I am new to Birt runtime engine.

Comment: I found one tutorial for [Jasper Reports](http://chathurangat.blogspot.qa/2012/03/jasperreports-with-php.html). I am searching exactly the similar way to BIRT-PHP. Hope you understand. Thank You.